# C# app doesn't work on virtualbox

Tags: c#, virtualbox

I create some app on c#. This app get some functionality from C++ DLL, and works correctly on non virtual systems (Win7 x64, Win8.1 x64).

But on Virtualbox with Win8.1 x64 app doesn't work correctly. I write all exeptions and errors to .txt log file, and in this file i get next error for each call DLLImport:

> Unable to load DLL 'someDll.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).

DLL file is located with all bin and executable files of app.

How i can fix that?

Comment: Make sure you have installed the correct .net framework version. 
and also check the x64 / x86 compatibility .

Comment: Ensure the paths for the dll's are correct.  Consider using relative paths.

Comment: I use relative path. But for test this error, i set full path to my dll. But app still doesn't work, and i get same error. om virtualbox installed .Net framework 4.5. I get this error only on virtual box,  and still don't know why...

Comment: Two suggestions. First, try starting your app with "Run as Administrator". Second, make a small app with minimal functionality that would simulate same conditions as your real app and see if it works differently.

Comment: installer unzip my app to some folder, and after this i run cmd command line as administrator, and try to execute my app. Ihave one think... set full name to my assembly and put it to GAC...but i don't believe that its will work...

Comment: Native dlls are not found from bin. They are supposed to be loaded from folders such as system32.

Comment: Only on virtualbox or generally? Because on normall system it works. And if i need load it from system 32, it must be loaded by special way? I copy my c++ dll to C:\Windows\System32, and app still can't found dll file...

Comment: Did you try copying C++ DLLs to your app folder? And what exactly does "cmd command line" do?

Comment: c++ dll already located in my app folder. By cmd i go to my app folder by cd command and execute my app with needed arguments...

Comment: Can you try moving your cmd file into your app folder and execute it from there?

Comment: One other thing. Can you compare `Windows Environment Variables` on Windows where your app is working with ones on VirtualBox guest?